# Expand a variable and wrap it in quotes

Tags: powershell

Consider this snippet:

```
$foo = "b a r"
Some-Cmdlet -MyParam $foo
```

I'd like to pass `b a r` as `-MyParam` parameter. It obviously won't work because the call will evaluate to:

```
Some-Cmdlet -MyParam b a r
```

and spaces will split the parameter into 3 separate characters. I could add quotes like this:

```
Some-Cmdlet -MyParam '"'+$foo+'"'
```

but I was wondering if there's a way to add the quotes without concatenating them while expanding the variable. In other words: without using `+`. Probably something like this:

```
Some-Cmdlet -MyParam "\"$foo\""
```

had `\` been an escape operator.

Comment: Are you trying to pass a variable into a cmdlet and want to add quotes to the variable value? Depending on how the variable is formed you can add the quotes to the string on the variable when you first set it, (e.g., `$myvar = "\`"my value\`""`. The backtick \` is an escape character in Powershell.

Comment: "*It obviously won't work because the call will evaluate to: `Some-Cmdlet -MyParam b a r` and spaces will split the parameter into 3 separate characters.*" - how is that obvious? Of course it won't do that - even if the language ran the interactive command line parser on the content of a variable (why would it?) and did split the string by spaces, the parameter wouldn't be three separate chars because arrays are not space delimited, it would be one char and an error of two unknown positional arguments.

Comment: Like, it would have taken you way less time to try it than to write all that and format it: [example on TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P600L7kkMz9PoSS1uEShWqEgsSgxV0OlQlNBSVelQldJoZZLJS0/X8FWQSlJIVGhSIkLrFC3QgEk/P8/AA)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about the interpretation of the string is incorrect.  If you pass a string, it stays a string.

```
Function '/a r g 1'
"$($Args[0])"
> /a r g 1
```